# OS X Photos removes 5 photos when converting to iCloud Photos

Tags: icloud, photos

When I try to convert my local Photos.app library to iCloud, the amount of photos in the library decreases from 686 to 681. I have tried to convert my local library multiple times but the problem keeps happening. I have found one of those 5 photos, but the file doesn't seem to be damaged.


The library was created in OS X 10.10.3 and I am currently running 10.10.4. Is this a bug in the app? What can I do to prevent these photos from getting deleted while enabling iCloud Photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting AppleCare, it seemed I had a database error. The problem was forwarded to the iCloud engineers and has now been fixed.